# Varnish for coconut wood

Tags: varnishing

Does coconut wood need special care? Would any primer and varnish do? I am making a plaque for my front door (to hold some brass numbers). The piece of wood i have is about 5mm thick.

Thanks,

Pablo

Comment: This question probably belongs on https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/ instead of Home Improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to finish it like any other wood.

Coconut timber is [not a hardwood/softwood](https://www.keimlumber.com/exotic-wood-library/coconut-palm) but it is used as a [hardwood substitute](http://www.cocowood.net/index.php/cocowood-resources). It does not have any weird chemical properties that prevent you from finishing it like any other wood with a varnish. Sometimes coconut timber does have [big pores](https://www.wisnofurniturefinishing.com/2011/08/coconut-wood-for-furniture.html) that you should fill before finishing it.

You can definitely finish it with a varnish, you'd probably want a spar varnish since it's going to be outside so the [additional UV protection](https://thewoodwhisperer.com/articles/difference-between-spar-varnish-and-regular-varnish/) would help with longevity.